# Showing that the function $f(t,y) = 1 + t \sin ty ,\quad 0 \leq t \leq 2$ satisfies the Lipschitz condition

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, lipschitz-functions

> $$f(t,y) = 1 + t \sin ty ,\quad 0 \leq t \leq 2$$

Here is as far as I have gotten -
\begin{align*}
|f(t, u) - f(t,y)| & = |1 + t\sin tu - 1 - t\sin tv|\\
& = t\cdot |\sin tu - \sin tv|\\
& = t\cdot |\sin tu - \sin tv|\\
& \le t\cdot |tu - tv|\\
& = t^2|u-v|
\end{align*}

Is the inequality allowed?

So the function is Lipschitz with $L = 4$. It is the dropping the $\sin$ part I am not sure about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your step would be allowed if you knew $|\sin(x) - \sin(y)| \le |x-y|$ to be true, i.e. if you knew that the function $\sin$ is $1$-Lipschitz.

Comment: After googling a bit I read that $sin$ is Lipschtitz with $L = 2$. So does that mean I should have a final answer in my question of $L = 8$ instead of $L = 4$?

Comment: Curious to know which website indicate Lipschitz = 2 for the sine.

Comment: I found it here - http://uk.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090514030319AANZ1Uy

Comment: @Did Yahoo! Answers is a veritable fountain of wisdom. "The sine function takes values from 1 to -1 so no matter what inputs you throw at this beast, the output will never vary by more then 2! So if you take your filter to be 2 you are guaranteed that | f(x) - f(y) | ≤ 2. Thus, sin(x) is a Lipschitz function."

Comment: Just to be sure everybody gets it right (yes, I have seen worse on MSE): @5pm's first sentence is a JOKE and Y!A quote is absurd.